# GraphQL: Get partial string matches

Tags: javascript, mongodb, graphql

I'm accessing a mongoDB collection via graphQL. This is the DB data:

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59ee1be762494b1df1dfe30c"),
    "itemId" : 1,
    "item" : "texture",
    "__v" : 0
}
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("59ee1bee62494b1df1dfe30d"),
    "itemId" : 1,
    "item" : "pictures",
    "__v" : 0
}
```

The query `{ todo(item: "texture"){ itemId, item } }` results in

```
{
  "data": {
    "todo": [
      {
        "itemId": 1,
        "item": "texture"
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

But I need to find datasets, which partially matching the given string.
So the string `tur` should result in both datasets: tex**tur**e, pic**tur**es

My graphQL Schema looks like this:

```
var schema = new GraphQLSchema({
  query: new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: 'RootQueryType',
    fields: {
      todo: {
        type: new GraphQLList(todoType),
        args: {
          item: {
            name: 'item',
            type: new GraphQLNonNull(GraphQLString)
          }
        },
        resolve: (root, {item}, source, fieldASTs) => {
          var projections = getProjection(fieldASTs)
          var foundItems = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
            ToDoMongo.find({item}, projections, (err, todos) => {
              err ? reject(err) : resolve(todos)
            })
          })
          return foundItems
        }
      }
    }
  })
})
```

Comment: Can you paste `ToDoMongo.find` method code? We need to know how you construct the query, because this is something that has to be tweaked to support what you want.

Comment: @cbartosiak In the posted schema you see the resolve() code. There you see the `ToDoMongo.find()`. So there I have to use a regex?

Comment: Yes, a regex is the input for Mongo `find` method. This is Mongo responsibility to do such a job you're interested in.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In general you have to construct the (mongo) query like the following:

```
{ "item": /tur/ }
```

This is a short syntax for `$regex` operator. You should construct this query in your `ToDoMongo.find` method code.